# JSON Exception No Value for specific value from JSON file data

Tags: java, arrays, json, exception

The following code successfully reads the JSON data and puts it inside an array. Later, when I try to retrieve a specific value from the array, the code gives an exception NO Value for the same, despite of the JSON file having a value declared to it.

DownloadTask - AsyncTask - OnPostExecute

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

       try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            String champinfo = jsonObject.getString("data");
            JSONObject championdata = new JSONObject(champinfo);
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            array.put(championdata);
       
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonpart  = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonpart.getString("name");     //Error Line :: 126 -  No Value
                String imagename = jsonpart.getString("full");
            }
           }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

LogCat:

```
System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for name

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:400)

W/System.err:     at com.example.guessthechampion.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:126)
```

JSON Data:

```
 "data": {
    "Aatrox": {
      "version": "9.3.1",
      "id": "Aatrox",
      "key": "266",
      "name": "Aatrox",
      "title": "the Darkin Blade", ............. goes on for 140+ champions
```

I'm a beginner in Android Studio and trying to learn on my own with some courses online. First Application to test my knowledge :P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.json.JSONException: No value for name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113727/org-json-jsonexception-no-value-for-name)

Comment: Your logcat shows a call to `.get()` but nowhere in your code is there a call to this method.   Also, when I try to run your code on the data you have posted, I get an error `JSONObject[data] is not a string`.  Please ensure you are running the code you posted and that it reproduces the error you mention, and update the code and/or logcat as necessary.  Right now, it's very difficult to help you because we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input @MartinZeiter. I wish I could say Yes :( I tried every suggestion provided , but no luck !! :(   

To be more clear, when I try to log the string value of the JSONArray 'array', then I get the complete JSON data logged with the name value. So I believe that the array has the value but for some reason I couldn't get the value retrieved. Weird to me :/

Comment: Thanks for your input @LukeWoodward. Exactly the same doubt I had, when I first saw the Logcat message. I don't have any call to this get() method throughout the code. And, Secondly when I try to log the JSONObject[data], it returns the complete JSON data for me as a string value. To make sure of all these, I rebuilt the code and ran onceagain,Its all the same :( Weird Again !!